# Trying to break the text in 2 line with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, break

I'm trying to break the text in 2 lines with React using \n but it's not working
This is my text
para: "Complete tasks faster than ever before. With our platform, it only takes minutes.",

and I wanted to be like this :
para: "Complete tasks faster than ever before.
With our platform, it only takes minutes.",

but using \n is not working, any other solution?

Comment: As a general rule, it's not a good idea to rely on whitespace being maintained as it's passed through a compiling the react app/parsed by the browser. Things like multiple-spaces and newlines are often condensed to single spaces before they ever reach the browser. Long way of saying: I'd suggest picking an answer that uses layout elements and/or CSS rather than `\n` and whiteSpace formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "\n" to work you need to add css property style={{whiteSpace: "pre-line"}}

```
function ReactApp(){
     const text = "Complete tasks faster than ever before.\n With our platform, it only takes minutes."
     return (
         <div style={{whiteSpace: "pre-line"}} >{text}</div>
     )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `<br />` html tag if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

I suggest solving this using styling, not content-driven. If you reduce the width of your `div` element, the text will break by default.

Answer (score 0):

Split them up into separate `<p>` tags, or put a `<br>` tag in between the,.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to put the text into separate containers (e.g divs).

Eventually, you can try to use the `white-space: pre-line` property.

e.g

```
.break-line {
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

and then in render do such:

```
render() {
   return <div className="break-line">Complete tasks faster than ever before. \n With our platform, it only takes minutes</div>
}
```

it should do the job. In case of any questions don't hesitate to ask! You can read more about the white-space property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in span like :

```
<span>Your Text</span><br>
<span>Next Text</span>
```